# Tables vs Views : Network speed?

Tags: sql, postgresql

At the moment my application uses an ORM to handle DB Queries. However, when I activated the DB logs, I noticed that it uses multiple queries for joining and fetching simple data such as using the username instead of the user id, filtering on a related table etc.

This leads to the ORM running almost 4-5 queries for a single lookup and thus when loading certain pages (with multiple API calls) it easily runs into 30-35 queries.

I'm planning on creating SQL Views to fetch queries with simple joins so that it can reduce the no of network round trips required when processing a single request.

Considering that the product is in its pre-alpha stage, is this premature optimisation or can this actually provide a faster user experience?

Comment: Your code may be misusing CRUD functionality, and pulling a thread that comes with all the graph of objects behind it. CRUD is awesome during the initial stages of an app (or when prototyping) since you can build applications fast without even looking at SQL. However, past this initial stage I would refrain from using CRUD, and I would go for more tailored queries that could scale up.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of ORMs. They allow a developer to quickly use native language features to access a RDBMS and turn out new features quickly; they also allow a developer to be completely ignorant of the chaos being unleashed under the hood which is easily missed when working with a small development database. If you prefer an ORM tool for data access then be very careful to profile the SQL it spits out and if performance is of any concern, evaluate what's actually going on *before* you ship it!

Answer (score 1):

Using a view is quite fine, but if you end up having one view per join your application needs, that could end up being a large number of views. I would explore the capabilities of your ORM some more, and if it truly is not able to generate joins, I would recommend using different software.